# Organisation - singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

In formal (not colloquial) English, is an organisation such as a sports club singular, plural, or is it discretionary?  E.g. is it preferable to write "The X club WAS formed" or "The X club WERE formed", or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 4):

Both "club" and "organization" are examples of [collective nouns.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/collective+noun)  In standard American English we would always use singular verb agreement with both "club" and "organization."

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/

However, in British English the rules are somewhat different, and it is not uncommon to see plural verb agreement with collective nouns like this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun

Although it is not uncommon, it is not universal.  In fact as stated in the Wikipedia article referenced, often the distinction is in the context of the usage.

> In British English, it is generally accepted that collective nouns can
> take either singular or plural verb forms depending on the context and
> the metonymic shift that it implies. For example, "the team is in the
> dressing room" (formal agreement) refers to the team as an ensemble,
> whilst "the team are fighting among themselves" (notional agreement)
> refers to the team as individuals.

In the context of the example you provided, i.e. formation of a club, formal agreement appears to be the most commonly used.  A search of the [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) shows only one example of "club were formed" whereas "club was formed" occurs nine times.

Thank you to @snailboat for helping to improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's answered my question - I favoured the singular in spite of being of British extraction

Comment: I'd say 'the club/team were formed' is just plain wrong. Mind you, I don't like the 'England was beaten' the Aussies like to announce either. Since it's acceptable over there, I can't say it's wrong, but it sounds wrong to my ears.